# Word VSTO is interrupting Windows shutdown

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, vsto, office-addins, word-interop

Existing solutions for similar questions don't work for me.

I need to close the Word application without saving the document. So if a document is open and the user closes the word application `DocumentBeforeClose` event is fired.

This is the existing code

```
Private Sub OnDocumentBeforeClose(ByVal doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
        'Some code
End Sub
```

1st I tried to close the application

```
Private Sub OnDocumentBeforeClose(ByVal doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
    'Some code
    doc.Close()  'This closed the open document but the application remained open, the user had the click X twice to close the application
    doc.Close(SaveChanged:= False) 'then I tried this but same result as above
    _application.DisplayAlerts = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdAlertLevel.wdAlertsNone ' Did nothing
End Sub
```

I cannot just `Quit()` the application in the `DocumentBeforeClose` event handler because in the application when the user switches the document (from a list of documents) the current open document needs to be closed before opening the next document. So if a user is trying to switch document then `DocumentBeforeClose` event is fired therefore I cannot implement `Quit()` here.

2nd I tried this

```
Private Sub OnDocumentBeforeClose(ByVal doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
    'Some code
    _application.ActiveDocument.Saved = True
    _application.ActiveDocument.SaveNormalPrompt = False
End Sub
```

3rd I tried this

```
AddHandler _application.DocumentBeforeSave, AddressOf OnBeforeSave

Private Sub OnDocumentBeforeClose(ByVal doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
    'Some code
    If Not Doc.Saved Then
        Doc.SaveAs2()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OnBeforeSave(ByVal doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document, ByRef SaveAsUI As Boolean, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
    SaveAsUI = False 'Saves the document without showing Save dialog
    Cancel = True 'then I tried Cancel, shows the Save dialog. Then tried both SaveAsUI and Cancel but did not help
End Sub
```

I have spent days and now I desperately need a solution for this. Can someone please help with this?

Comment: ```SaveAsUI = Flase```. Is **Flase** just a typo in this question or also in your code?

Comment: @HelO'Ween it was a typo. Thanks for noticing. Any idea how can I solve the issue?

Comment: Sorry, unfortunately not. I haven't worked with any MS Office product with .NET so far.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works like a charm on my machine and I don't get any dialogs for saving the changed document when Word is being closed:

```
Private Sub OnDocumentBeforeClose(ByVal doc As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
        doc.Saved = True
End Sub
```